# unity container - registration for Idataprotector

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-container

the below registration code is for structuremap.

```
For<IDataProtector>().Use(() => new DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
```

**what is the equivalent registration in unity?**

it gives error when I tried as below.

```
container.RegisterType<IDataProtector>(() => new DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
container.RegisterType<IDataProtector>(new InjectionFactory(c => new DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.NET Identity")));
```